# What happens to foreign stocks if my country goes to war with that country?

Tags: stocks, foreign

For example, people in the US who owned stock in German companies in 1941.  Have there been other examples other than Germany?

Are there any investment strategies that would protect assets in case of war?  Please give examples of strategies that have been tested in the past.

Comment: The assets were probably frozen, and unfrozen after the war.  If the company still exists afterwards, you'd still own that fraction.

Comment: Do you appreciate how complicated and rare it would be for a US citizen/national to own anything in Germany in 1941?

Comment: @RonJohn: That seems like an answer to me... :)

Comment: @quid if a US national bought the German equities before September 1939, he'd have little other choice than to hold on to it until Germany's war with Britain and the USSR were over.

Comment: My point is it's not as though the person could hop on the internet and buy a foreign security in 1941

Comment: @quid No, but they could probably contact a brokerage firm in Germany and have them buy it and mail the stock certificate to the US.

Comment: @quid you're thinking "middle class".  Think *upper class* instead, like someone who owns a mid-sized urban bank.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm surprised the foreign government doesn't just confiscate your shares as a "tax on the enemy".

Comment: The enemy could do that, too....

Comment: Yep, both sides could do that.  So I guess killing each other is ok, but confiscating each other's money is going too far!

Comment: You guys are right, this is definitely something worth considering.  That just after the depression and in the middle of the war, it was reasonably common for folks in the US to own securities in foreign, enemy, nations.  Hitler, and the extremely protectionist national socialist party, definitely would not have appropriated assets owned by foreign enemies in the war.  The five or US people who owned german equity in the middle of ww2 would definitely have gotten their ownership back afterwards.

Comment: As a curiosity related to your example, you might want to check the story of [Fanta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fanta) although of course it is not as if these situations always follow the same process.

Comment: @RonJohn, no.  I'm not.  I'm saying no matter who owned anything in 1941, the answer to this question is of absolutely no consequence to this person **and** would have had no broad application at the time either.  There is no telling what future governments will do in future world wars.  This person is likely trying to quantify their risk in foreign securities, when opening the position wouldn't have been an option in the timeframe referenced and the outcome is in no way to be relied upon for possible future world wars. This problem is of no concern to this person, is the point of my comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an open-ended, hypothetical question. Please see https://money.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I think this question is on-topic. The risks of investing in a country which might be involved in a war with your counry should be known ot a private investor. But using WW2 as an example might not be that good. the world has changed a lot in the past 75 years.

Comment: Yep, i think its important to explore the risks by trying to examine previous examplrs.  The Germany example was not mine, as my question was 100% edited by another person.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of potential risks if tensions are high even if war does not occur.  Sanctions could force divestment, the other country may nationalize the company, etc.

The nationalization of oil companies in Venezuela is one example.

https://www.reuters.com/article/us-venezuela-nationalization/venezuela-seizes-operations-from-oil-majors-idUSN0149302220070501